# Server 2008 have no internet access

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

Hi I have a windows server 2008 which is acting as the only DNS and DC in my network. But the server is not connected to the internet. So that im using the public DNS servers in all the client machines.

Servers TCP/IP:
IP:192.168.x.2
subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.x.1(The IP address of the modem provided by ISP)
Primary DNS:192.168.x.2(I just pointed to itself)

Client Machines Tcp/IP:

IP:192.168.x.x
subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.x. 1(The IP address of the modem provided by ISP)
Primary DNS: Public DNS Provided by ISP

If i point the client machines to my local DNS the client machines are not connected with the internet.
Im just a beginner. Can any one help me out of this.

Note:

1. My server connects to internet if i connects through proxy.

Answer (score 0):

To have your clients resolve names via your DNS server (which you want to do so that they will be able to resolve the domain), you need to allow your DNS server to forward queries or do recursive name resolution.  There are a few ways you can do this.

By far the easiest way is to specifically allow the DNS server to make DNS requests (on port 53) to the internet, and either set up forwarders (eg. to your ISP), or configure it to do its own recursion.  You don't need to open any other connectivity for this, and there is no appreciable security risk from it.  Then, configure your DC as the DNS server for the workstations.

You can also set up another server to do DNS.  Configure it to forward requests for names in your domain to your DC, and forward the rest.  Configure this server as the DNS server for your workstations and your DC.  Doing this complicates your network and provides no material benefit over the previous solution.

Third, you could set up a DNS proxy on your LAN which the DC can use as a forwarder.  The DNS proxy is basically a DNS server which forwards its requests to your ISP's DNS servers.  Of course, this server could also do its own recursive queries.  Set this server as the forwarder on your DC, and have clients use the DC as a DNS server.  This also is unnecessarily complex, but will work.

Keep in mind that having only one DC and having that DC use itself as its only DNS resolver is definitely not good practice and tends to create reliability issues.  You should really have two of them, and have them resolve DNS for each other, with themselves as a backup.

Using residential gateway style equipment provided by ISPs (the modem/NAT-router/WAP/switch/firewall combo people erroneously call a router) is also usually bad practice and will tend to create reliability issues.

Comment: Hi @Falcon, Thanks for writing. I tried to add forwarders but it was unable to resolve the public DNS ip's. My problem now is, the server itself is not connected with the internet. I can understand that it would be better if I have more than One server, but we have just started our business and we can put more money on that. So, can you help me how can I get this resolved with single server. 

When all the client systems, connect to internet having gateway as my router's ip and public dns server. Why my server 2008 is not connected with the internet with the same settings.

Comment: If you are using a domain, you should not be using public DNS resolvers except as forwarders.  AD domains are extremely dependent on DNS and your environment needs to be able to resolve in your domain.  My second answer explains what to do with only one server.